# audioqueue is block when recording aac

Tags: ios, audio

I am using apple's audioqueue to recording aac data to memory but the callbakc function is always block unlike recording the pcm data, is there anything more to do? if u know please give a help,thanks

Comment: Have you got some example code for what you've tried so far?

Comment: yea,I have it for aac as I understood it just need to change it format,do you have any ideas ?